# ignore certain mercurial commands in mercurial hook

Tags: python, mercurial, hook, mercurial-hook

I have a mercurial hook like so:

```
[hooks]
pretxncommit.myhook = python:path/to/file:myhook
```

with the code looking like this:

```
def myhook(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    #do some stuff
```

but this hook runs on commands that use the commit logic to do something else, in my case `hg shelve`. is there a way to get the command that the user has input to avoid running the hook on that command?

perhaps something like this:

```
def myhook(ui, repo, command, **kwargs):
      if command is "hg shelve"
           return 0
      #do some stuff
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the answer seems to be no. I just debugged into the hook mechanism of hg 3.1, and the information about which command was issued is not propagated into the hook function. The only way I can think of is to hack something ugly with the debugger api to extract informations from the call stack.

Another hack would be to inspect `sys.argv`, but I fear that this is also very unreliable (as it can't detect if something was executed via the [Command Server](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommandServer)).

BTW I used this snippet to attach a debugger:

```
def myhook(ui, repo, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
    from pdb import set_trace
    set_trace()
```